# Is there really a difference between referencing and creating new object from reference of PrintStream?

Tags: java, bluej

Below are the two ways of getting reference of the `PrintStream` object:

```java
class Ex1 {
    public static void printEx() {
        //line 1: Direct Reference
        PrintStream ps1 = System.out;
        //line 2: Passing Reference as argument in constructor
        PrintStream ps2 = new PrintStream(System.out);
    }
}
```

Is there really a significant difference between those two lines in terms of usage or can (or should) it be used interchangeably?

Comment: [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). **Always** check the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take as a reference [this page](http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/java/how-system-out-println-work-in-java.php);

```
import java.io.*;
public class SystemOutPrintlnDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    //creating PrintStream object
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
    ps.println("Hello World!");
    ps.print("Hello World Again!");
    //Flushes the stream
    ps.flush();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, because if you look at the System class, `out` is just a static variable of type `PrintStream`

```
PrintStream printStream = System.out;

printStream.println("TEST");
```

Although, I am not sure why you would want to do that. And what would be the impact of doing that.

Comment: "not sure why" for example, if you want a method to be able to print to standard output, standard error, a file, a network socket etc, you can pass in a `PrintStream` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

System is a final class with a static member called `out` of type [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). For this reason you call the method like `System.out.println()`

The method `println()` returns type void, hence you cannot create an object with that method.